# Find necessary and sufficient conditions for the sequence $u_{n}$ to be bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider the sequence: $$u_{n}=ξλ₁ⁿ⁺¹+ηλ₂ⁿ⁺¹+δ$$

where $ξ,λ₁,η,λ₂,δ$ are real numbers. My question is: Find necessary and sufficient conditions for the sequence $u_{n}$ to be bounded, i.e., $$|u_{n}|≤M$$ for some real $M$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint***

**Added** *Let's take the general case and assume that $\xi\ne0$ and $\eta\ne0$*

The geometric sequence $(a^n)_n$ is bounded if and only if $|a|\le1$ so  prove that the given sequence is bounded if and only if
$$\left(|\lambda_1|\le1\land|\lambda_2|\le1\right)\lor(\lambda_1=\lambda_2\land\xi=-\eta)$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Take $\lambda_1 = \eta = 2$, and $\lambda_2 = \xi = 0$.

Comment: The pesky problem of $\eta=0$ or $\xi=0$ complicates the formulation of a condition equivalent to boundedness. If you assume neither of these is zero, I think your answer is correct. I'm sure that's what you were thinking. Sorry if I sound pedantic, but it really is true.

Comment: @MPW I edited my answer taking in consideration your comment.